# NServiceBus's custom logging implementation with AsyncLocal throwing exceptions

Tags: asynchronous, logging, azure-service-fabric, nservicebus, race-condition

We have a custom logging implementation for NServiceBus that adds properties to logs; it does this by storing it in a IDictionary object that is managed by an AsyncLocal class.

When we add:

`NServiceBus.Logging.LogManager.Use<OurCustomFactory>();`

To the service we run into `The given key was not present in the dictionary`, `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` and `Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object[]'` exceptions; this, I think, is due to race conditions of different threads accessing and changing our Dictionary.

I'm at at ends with the code; I tried wrapping it in locks and that didn't work, I've tried playing around with the async/await code to ensure nothing is left being awaited; I've even removed some of the code that adds the properties but this still has an effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to provide the implementation of your custom logging factory.

Comment: So the problem we had is that we had some shared components between the Behaviours and the Handlers; in NServiceBus the Behaviours are always singletons whilst the Handlers aren't. This is why we were getting the above error.